# Image not uploading in db django cbv

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am using class based views for a form but image is not uploading in db, not showing any errors.
here is my models.py

```
class ProductCreateModel(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey('accounts.SellerProfileModel',
                    related_name='product_seller',
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,editable=False)
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug            = models/.SlugField(max_length=255,unique=True,blank=True)
    description     = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    orignal_price   = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)
    discount        = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=4)
    discount_price  = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=8)
    image1           = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path,blank=True,null=True)
```

here is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import ProductCreateModel
class ProductCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductCreateModel
       fields = '__all__'
```

here is my views.py

```
class ProductCreateView(views.LoginRequiredMixin,ActiveSellerOnlyMixin,generic.CreateView,):
template_name = 'products/create_new_product.html'
model = ProductCreateModel
form_class = ProductCreateForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
def form_valid(self, form):

    product = form.save(commit=False)
    user =  get_current_user(self.request)
    image1 = form.cleaned_data['image1']
    form.instance.user = request.user
    return super(ProductCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
    # product.save()
```

Now the form is submitted successfully but image is empty.

Comment: whats the image path, is it in the media folder?

Comment: def get_filename_ext(filepath):
    base_name = os.path.basename(filepath)
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(base_name)
    return name, ext

def upload_image_path(instance, filename):
    print('this is here')
    new_filename = random.randint(1,3910209312)
    name, ext = get_filename_ext(filename)
    final_filename = '{new_filename}{ext}'.format(new_filename=new_filename, ext=ext)
    print('path returning')
    return"product/media/images/{user}/{new_filename}/{final_filename}".format( new_filename=new_filename,  final_filename=final_filename,user=instance.user)

Comment: if i need to edit the question? for defining the upload image path

Comment: Post your form template html file.

Comment: {% extends 'products/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

  <div class="container">
      <h1>Submit Form</h1>
      <form class="firstform" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form %}

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn default" value="Submit">
      </form>
  </div>

{% endblock %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <form class="firstform" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %} {% bootstrap_form form %} <input type="submit" class="btn btn default" value="Submit"> </form>
```

to

```
 <form class="firstform"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %} {% bootstrap_form form %} <input type="submit" class="btn btn default" value="Submit"> </form>
```

add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to form in html.

When you are writing client-side code, all you need to know is use `multipart/form-data` when your form includes any `<input type="file">` elements.If you want know why see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean).